# Pretty-print a nested dataframe in R with purrr::map

Tags: r, nested, purrr

I'd like to pretty print a nested dataframe (tibble).

Here is a minimal example

```
df <- tribble(~name,~data,
"first",tibble(type=c("a","b","c"),value=c(2,4,5)),
"second",tibble(type=c("a","b"),value=c(3,1)))
```

so that:

```
  name   data            
  <chr>  <list>          
1 first  <tibble [3 × 2]>
2 second <tibble [2 × 2]>
```

I would like to print data as follows (i.e. using the variable `name` as title for each `data` item):

```
 first
   type  value
 1 a         2
 2 b         4
 3 c         5

 second
   type  value
 1 a         3
 2 b         1
```

I am sure this must be possible using `purrr::map` or some similar function, but I haven't been able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~name,~data,
              "first",tibble(type=c("a","b","c"),value=c(2,4,5)),
              "second",tibble(type=c("a","b"),value=c(3,1)))

deframe(x = df)
#> $first
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   type  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2
#> 2 b         4
#> 3 c         5
#> 
#> $second
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   type  value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         3
#> 2 b         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>